# SAP_UI component 7.52 minimum SAPUI5 version

Tags: sapui5

since I cant find anything on the internet regarding this question, I thought to try it here.

When I update my sap_ui component from 7.51 sp05 to 7.52 sp00, do I have to update all my apps to sapui5 version 1.52 aswell? (currently they're on 1.44)
And additionally, if my gateway(gw_fnd) is still on 7.51 could it cause problems when i update the sap_ui component to a newer release?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the published SAPUI5 version history here:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/versionoverview.html

We recommend you to upgrade SAPUI5 from 1.44 to 1.52 via the Front-end-server upgrade. (see SAP Note 2484979), in which case you need Fiori Front-end-server 4.0 SP01.
The standard apps with SAPUI5 1.44 delivered by SAP should be compatible with the new SAPUI5 1.52 – in the exceptional case it is necessary to upgrade the Fiori app with the newest SP patch.
If you experience compatibility issue with the 1.52, please raise an incident ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to restrict all your current apps to the version in which they were developed and upgrade slowly after going through appropriate testing cycle when you have time and budget. This will not stop the upgrade as well as your application will keep on working and you do not have to spend testing efforts right away.